# Temporarly disable cache in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, performance, cache

I want to disable the caching for my session in oracle 11g to see how long a query takes.

Is this possible or is there a better way for meassuring the time a query takes to run?

Comment: You could for example enable tracing of session in SQL*Plus.

Comment: Which cache? Oracle's buffer cache? The file system cache? The cache inside your harddisk? The cache built into your harddisk controller? There is so many caching going on in a modern computer, you won't be able to disable all of it. I would compare/monitor the logical I/O a statement does. This can be obtained e.g. using SQL*Plus' "autotrace" facility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle caches (placed in System Global area) can not be turned off. 
You can only increase or decrease the size of these caches.